How to use INNER JOINS in Update query in IBM Data Studio
Hi I am trying to update the tables using the below query which has joins, but IBM Data studio is not accepting the JOIN statements and saying invalid use. Can you please help me
UPDATE AVGI06.VISS_IP_PO PO

SET   PO.END_TS        = '2024-04-30-00.00.00.000000'
      ,PO.LST_UPDTD_USER_ID  = 'DATA FIX'`
      ,PO.LST_UPDTD_TS       = CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 MICROSECOND`
INNER JOIN AVGI06.VIPISS_ID            VIPISS   ON PO.INS_ID = VIPISS.INS_ID
INNER JOIN AVGI06.VISS_AFLN_ROLE       AFLNROLE ON AFLNROLE.ISS_AFLN_ID = PO.ISS_AFLN_ID
INNER JOIN AVGI06.VIP_PO_DESC          DESC     ON DESC.PO_ID = AFLNROLE.PO_ID
INNER JOIN AVGI06.VC_PO_SPLR_ISSR      SPLRISSR ON DESC.SPLR_PO_ID= SPLRISSR.PO_ID  
WHERE _ISS_AFLN_ID         = 1

IBM Studio is showing an invalid use of INNER JOIN

see docs: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-update  (Example 10 has a JOIN)

conclusion: you need a FROM tablename between the SET, and the INNER JOIN

table alias PO is used in the first join - but you have forgotten to include that table in the (missing) FROM clause. ALSO include the table alias in the final line. Which table does the column _ISS_AFLN_ID come from?
